# probability of this event happening

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

Play $(n+1)t$ rounds of the same coin-tossing game and the coin is fair ($n$ is a fixed natural number). Please help me find the following probability:

> $P$(the number of rounds of tossing that show head is no less than $t$ after all the tossing is done, and at any time point during, the number of coin landing head is no less than $1/n$ of that of tail).

If possible, please also show that when $t \to \infty$, this probability becomes/does not become $0$.

What I think: If n=1, it is similar to the Catalan number. In this more general case, I can calculate the probability of the number of head landings being x after all the tossing, with x between 0 and (n+1)t. Aggregate this on the interval [t,(n+1)t] can get the probability without the restriction of 'at any time point during ... no less than 1/n of that of tail'. Basically I followed the approach used in [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter12.pd%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bf). Between page 473 & 475 (theorem 12.1 till 12.3). But I do not know how to deal with the restriction, neither do I know how to evaluate the limit of this probability.

Comment: Verbatim from homework. What did you try?

Comment: I had a similar question before posted on this website - 2t rounds of tossing, exactly t times landing head and at any time during, number of head recorded is no less than that of tail. It turns out the probability of that happening goes to 0 when t goes to infinity. But what I want is a positive probability event. So now I try to manipulate the event a little bit in this question, hoping its probability will be asymptotically positive

Comment: Which says nothing about what you tried to solve the present question.

Comment: If n=1, it is similar to the Catalan number. In this more general case, I can calculate the probability of the number of head landings being x after all the tossing, with x between 0 and (n+1)t. Aggregate this on the interval [t,(n+1)t] can get the probability without the restriction of 'at any time point during ... no less than 1/n of that of tail'. Basically I followed the approach used in dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter12.pdf Between page 473 & 475 (theorem 12.1 till 12.3). But I do not know how to deal with the restriction and when taking limit.

Comment: Excellent! You might add all this to your question.